# "Recursive" (?) omitting of empty values in XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a target XML structure like this:

```
<object>
  <children>
    <object>
      <property name="Marketingfoto">
        <value>148-41_149-41.tif</value>
      </property>
      <property name="Produkttyp">
        <value/>
      </property>
      <property name="Produktname">
        <value language="en">Sealing</value>
        <value language="de">Dichtung</value>
      </property>
      <property name="ProduktnameMehrzahl">
        <value language="en"/>
        <value language="de">Dichtungen</value>
      </property>
```

As you can see, there are `value` elements without text. I want the XML Serializer to omit those, as they are taking up huge amounts of space in the resulting file.

Also, If a `property` element doesn't have any values with text in them, the whole `property` element should also be omitted.

So, it should basically "recursively" omit the elements if there is nothing to write, so that the resulting example looks like:

```
<object>
  <children>
    <object>
      <property name="Marketingfoto">
        <value>148-41_149-41.tif</value>
      </property>
      <property name="Produktname">
        <value language="en">Sealing</value>
        <value language="de">Dichtung</value>
      </property>
      <property name="ProduktnameMehrzahl">
        <value language="de">Dichtungen</value>
      </property>
```

How can I go about this? I tried using the `ShouldSerialize` method, but it doesn't seem to work on this particular serialization attribute combination.

The classes are:

```
[XmlRoot("object")]
public class XmlObject
{
    [XmlArray("children")]
    [XmlArrayItem("object")]
    public List<XmlObject> Children { get; set; }

public class XmlProperty
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("value")]
    public List<XmlPropertyValue> Values { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeValues()
    {
        return Values != null && Values.Count > 0;
    }
}

public class XmlPropertyValue
{
    [XmlAttribute("language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeValue()
    {
        return Value != null && !Value.Equals(String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use `ShouldSerialize` in various ways and the best I could get to was `<value />`, couldn't make him not serialize an array item basically.

But using a custom property to filter out what you don't want would work.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public List<XmlPropertyValue> Values { get; set; }

[XmlElement("value")]
public List<XmlPropertyValue> ValuesForSerialization
{
    get
    {
        var bla = Values.Where(o => o.ShouldSerializeValue()).ToList();
        return bla;
    }
    set { Values = value; }
}
```

Tested, it works. It's not a neat solution and neither is anything that adds public members to your class (just like `ShouldSerializeValue`).

According to some [sources](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2008/10/04/serializing-internal-types-using-xmlserializer.aspx) you could make `ValuesForSerialization` internal if you use `DataContractSerializer` instead of `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: Interesting solution. I will check into that.

Comment: After some more tries, I decided to just prevent adding values that do not have text in them. Seems to work nicely so far.